# Center align 'list group item' within Card in Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Does anyone know how to align the 'list-group-item' within Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6 update? I can add text-center to the card itself, which centrally aligns the card header and links, however the list group doesn't move.

I've tried the mx-auto class, this moves the text centrally, however the border is shrunk to only fit the text so looks out of place

[Example of card text center issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgQ98.png).

This is the code I've been testing on:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="card-block">
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `align-items-center` on the card..

```
  <div class="card align-items-center" style="width: 20rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block text-center">
            <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="card-block">
            <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
            <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
        </div>
  </div>
```

**Demo** http://www.codeply.com/go/cc1EYpkRSe

***EDIT*** Based on comments, you'd have to center align each `<li>` like this..

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush w-100 align-items-stretch">
   <li class="list-group-item text-center d-inline-block">Cras justo odio</li>
   <li class="list-group-item text-center d-inline-block">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
   <li class="list-group-item text-center d-inline-block">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey Zim, thanks for the reply, the issue with that is that the border/lines that separate the list items don't fill the width of the card when they are centered..?

Comment: Thanks Zim, that worked a charm, when I've got the reputation I'll upvote the reply!